# Multiply two 8 bit numbers

Tags: c, bit

I am trying to multiply two 8 bit numbers ans store the 16 bit result in two 8 bit variables, Eg :
91*16 = 1456 
High = 14 and Low = 56
This is the code I'm using but not getting desired result . Can someone point out my error please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include<time.h>

int main()
{
  uint8_t a = 91;
  uint8_t b = 16;
  uint16_t c = a*b;
  printf("Value at c is %d \n",c);
  uint8_t lo = c & 0x00FF;
  uint8_t hi = c >> 8;
  printf("Hi and lo value are %d and %d \n",hi,lo);
  return 0;
}
```

I get `Hi = 5` and `Lo = 176`, why is it so ?

Comment: Because `5*256+176=1456`

Comment: Looks right to me. What result were you expecting?

Comment: Try `uint16_t hi = c & 0xFF00;` note 16, not 8 bit - this should make things more clear.

Comment: Hi = 5 and Lo = 176 is the correct answer. The problem is with your initial assumption

Comment: Oh yeah! So if I want to store Hi = 14 and Lo =56 what do I need to do ?

Comment: @TanushreeBanerjee: `14*256 + 56 = 3640`. Or `104 * 35` yields in the most significant 8-bits `14` and the least significant 8-bits `56`

Comment: @TanushreeBanerjee.: Hope you understand what is being mentioned in answer.

Comment: Yes I understood your points guys..thanks for helping me! I'll  use @coderredoc , your method .thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Result of `a*b` is

```
0000 0101  1011 0000
(  5     )(   176   )
```

That is what you printed.
You mixed up decimal representation with others. The value you see is not stored like `0001 0100 0101 0110`. If it was, then yes you would get *your* desired result (But it is debatable how helpful it would be).

To get what you want, you might consider using `c%100` and `c/100`.(You are getting the most significant 2 digits in `hi` and rest two digits in `lo`).

```
  uint8_t lo = c %100;
  uint8_t hi = c /100;
```

And print them properly

```
printf("%" PRIu8 "\n", lo); //56
printf("%" PRIu8 "\n", hi); //14
```

In this way to be precise `printf("Hi and lo value are %" PRIu8" and %"PRIu8" \n",hi,lo);`.

Note that any 2 digit positive integer can be placed in `uint8_t` but to be more generic, you might want to consider that sometimes the resultant multiplication can be of 5 decimal digits.

Comment: is there any way to chnge it so that I get hi =14 and lo =56?

Answer (score 0):

If you want decimal representation (which doesn't make sense as decimal does not evenly divide byte values) you need to use /100 and %100 instead of bitwise operations.